# JavaScript RegEx to change a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to take strings in the following format:

```
http:\/\/img.mypath.net\/time\/daily\/2010\/1006\/my_image_name.jpg
```

And convert them to this, using JavaScript:

```
http://www.mynewpath.com/i/daily/2010/1006/77_my_image_name.jpeg
```

I'm sure that someone more fluent in RegEx than I can give a terse solution.

Comment: So the "V" turns intto "/" and the "W" turns into "www" right?

Comment: that's `\/\/` not `W`. Though it does look like the domain should change from "img.mypath.net" to "www.mynewpath.com" - again, a straight replace can do that.

Comment: Where does the 77 come from?  Also, do you have literal backslash characters in your data or not?  Because a JavaScript string literal containing `"\/"` is the same as one containing `"/"`.

Comment: I've just edited to convert both to `code` format (prefix with four spaces, or quote with backticks), to make characters clear. At the same time I removed double quotes, which I assume were not needed, but noting here in case that's relevant

Comment: I'd like to know the citeria for the `77` before giving a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
var url = 'http:\/\/img.mypath.net\/time\/daily\/2010\/1006\/my_image_name.jpg';    
url = url.replace('\\/', '/'); // Replace \/ by /
url = url.replace('img.mypath.net/time', 'www.mynewpath.com/i'); // Replace domain and first path.
url = url.replace(/([^/]+)$/g, '77_$1'); // Prefix last path with `77_` (???)
alert(url);
```

The requirement around `77` is unclear, but if it's fixed, the above should do.

Comment: There are more differences between the two URLs than simply the escaped backslashes. Thanks, though.

Comment: Your final regex can simply be `[^/]+$` with `77_$0` in the replacement side.

Comment: @jerome: That wasn't obvious in the original question. I updated my answer. @Peter: that's indeed better.

Comment: (This comment editing can get confusing... wish SO did some form of notification.) :)

Comment: @BalusC You've been a great help so far, but running the code above alerts the following.

http://www.mynewpath.com/i/daily/2010/1006/77_$0

Comment: @jerome: I reverted the fix after the comment of @Peter (which in theory should have worked!). It should now work.

Comment: You're welcome. Now I can finally go watch world cup football of Netherlands ;)